# Bootstrap JQUERY Plugin Not Working in Remote Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

product.php

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick_edit" href="quick_edit.php?productid=<?php print $row['productid'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></a>

<div class="modal" id="quick_edit" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the remote modal file [quick_edit.php]

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="text-danger fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="text-muted fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <strong>Product</strong></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <form method="post" id="productForm" name="productForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value=""  />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Enter tags</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="example-tags" name="example-tags" class="input-tags" value="HTML, CSS, Javascript">
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="confChange"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Change</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" name="reset"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>  Reset</button>
            </div>
      </div>
</form>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <br />
<div class="modal-footer">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>     
</div>
```

At the body part of MODAL, i want to use jquery plugin for TAGS, DATEPICKER, or other jquery plugin but it won't load

Thanks for expert solutions

Comment: You've tagged jQuery and mentioned calling jQuery plugins and loading the jQuery library - but you have not included any jQuery in your example! For somebody to be able to answer efficiently, please include the jQuery too, as that could be the cause. If your jQuery plugins aren't working, posting your HTML won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include *JQUERY*?

- Not uncluded
  Add this line into ur HTML, preferred somewhere at the bottom of the body so your page will be loading faster.`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Please also specify your question better, since we do not know *exactly* where you want to 'include' this *JQUERY* plugin.

Comment: jquery included in product.php

if i include it in quick_edit.php, it won't work too